# Didn't get the Electorate badge

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges

The site told me that I am very close to getting Electorate badge. I voted a bit, and then the system told me that I got it. I clicked on the link on my profile, and there was some text like "Baskakov_Dmitriy didn't get the badge". I clicked on the list of recommended badges to track -- Electorate isn't there. Apparently, something went wrong, and I cannot get it anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You now have this badge -- the system awarded it a couple of hours after you made this post.

Many badges don't arrive the instant you qualify. There are scripts that run throughout the day which check for people who should get a badge and award it to them. Badges not earned frequently are checked for fewer times per day, leading to potentially a few hours' wait time before a badge arrives.

(We didn't do anything on the diamond team since we don't have any control over badges.)

I'm not sure what messages you were seeing but I'm sorry to hear you had a confusing experience with that.

Congratulations on the shiny new gold badge!